# pasting from websites results in 1 long line..anyway to keep the paragraph format?

Tags: text-editing, copy-paste, fill-paragraph, paragraphs

when copy and pasting from any web site a paragraph and pasting into emacs with S-insert, the paragraph is always a very long line. is there anyway to keep the paragraph structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run `fill-paragraph` bound by default to `M-q`

Depending on where you are copying from, remember that the paragraph is one logical object, how it shows depends on the width of the browser on your screen. Emacs is doing the correct thing by not inserting extra newlines.

Comment: enabling `auto-fill-mode` works too. But, you'd have to enter a space after yanking a paragraph into emacs for it to automatically fill.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider pasting in Freeplane Mindmap and then copy the mindmap head and paste it into emacs. The mindmap tree will depend on indentations. If your website text is aligned correctly, you should get the needed paragraphs.